# Android : Intent Service with Networking libraries(Retrofit or Volley)

Tags: android, android-service, retrofit, retrofit2, intentservice

I am developing an app and one of the requirements of the app is to use Intent Service to do any network api calls.I am using retrofit for fetching data from api.The data fetching is not to be fetched continuously but on user request(like user clicks on some item).

So  why there is a need of Intent Service if i am using Retrofit and it fetches data asynchronously.Even if it is possible how can i use retrofit with intent service.Thankyou.

Comment: there is no reason why you **should** use IntentService, because Retrofit is async itself. But you can use if you want. There is nothing special about using it in IntentService. If you have some problem, tell us which exactly.

Comment: thanks..but does it make sense retrofit inside service.So how can i pass the requirement of using intent service.

Comment: For me it does not make sense for IntentService, but does makle sense for regular Service. `how can i pass the requirement` - you can use IntentService without Retrofit libraries, doing network operations in it.

Comment: Perhaps if the requirement is to use an IntentService for your network calls then instead of using the retrofit .enque(Callback<T>) method you could use the .execute() method to run your requests synchronously, but that would mean you'll need to catch any IO exception manually. Also doesn't make much sense either, but do let us know how you go about this eventually